# LogConfigurationException after migrating from log4j1.x to log4j2.x

Tags: log4j, log4j2, slf4j, tomahawk

I migrated `log4j` from `1.x` to `2.x`. After migration I am getting this error message:

```
org.apache.commoms.logging.LogConfigurationException: User-specified log class

org.apache.commons.logging.imple.Log4JLogger cannot be found or is not useable.
```

I verified that the `commons-logging-1.2.jar` file is available in `WEB-INF/lib`.

And also seen one more exception in console i.e:

```
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: source document: jar file tomahawk20-1.1.14.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml.

Cause: unable to create a new instance of org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ServerResourcePhaseLostener.
```

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to migrate from `log4j1.x` to `log4j2.x` then should import new `jar`.
Log4j2 jars: `log4j-api-2.y.z.jar`, `log4j-core-2.y.z.jar`

Also, there is a document help migrate from 1.x to 2.x. so, follow the documentation.

Link : [Migrating from Log4j 1.x](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html)